# Sandbox suggestion

Tags: support

We've had some long, complex and LaTeX-heavy answers recently, and so I'm suggesting that we create a thread *a la* [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) post on Math.SE. I doubt this will be used much, but there's a chance it could work in the future.

**Suggested guidelines:**

In general, see the ones posted on the Math thread. Here are some of the important points:

- Make posts community wiki.
- Do not make too many - perhaps set a limit here.
- Do not expect your work to stay alive forever, escaping deletion.
- When done, add a message indicating that the post is free, and delete your old work.

Comment: Note that SE already stores drafts of posts every few minutes, once they meet some minimum required length to enable that feature. Those drafts are then available to you when you reopen the thread you were writing it in, or can be dismissed. It's also possible to [force draft saving on demand](http://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand) via a user script.

Comment: @TildalWave Thanks; I didn't know that.

Comment: [object Object]